# kubernetes Ingress tls dosent work although the configuration seems to be correct

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

Good day!

I have 2 files

`my-domain.csr` and `my-domain.key`. The problem is that I have not been provided with a .pem or .crt

So I searched on the Internet and found out that you can get a `.crt` file by using `.csr` and `.key`. Which I did. To do this, I ran the command

```js
$ openssl x509 -req -in my-domain.csr -signkey my-domain.key -out my-domain.crt
```

and i got `my-domain.crt`

Next, I created a secret with the tls type

```
$ kubectl create secret tls my-tls-secret --cert=my-domain.crt  --key=my-domain.key
```

Next, I updated my ingress

```yaml
#ingress.yml

kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - my-domain.com
    secretName: my-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-app
            port:
              number: 80
```

and

```
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yml
```

But unfortunately, after all these manipulations, the ssl connection did not appear on my project

The real domain I stole under the alias my-domain there were no syntax or other errors in creating it. What could be my problem? What don't I understand

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in chrome secret window?

I think there are 2 reason,cache and missing service target..